# Is it possible to implement a StackADT in C using generics and not ints only?

Tags: c, generics, adt, implementation

I have recently started to learn C and was interested whether, like in java, it is possible to create a stack implementation  ADT where I will be able to allow the user to parse a certain data type to be initialized and stored. E.g. a stack that will be able to hold Strings if initialized with strings or booleans. This is a question that's been bothering me a little because if it impossible, then isn't C a very limited language?

Looking forward for answers

Comment: It's not possible if you mean Java's generics, and C is (deliberately) a limited language. A list of pointers can obviously store any kind of pointer, and GLib has a resizable [`GArray`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-Arrays.html) datatype that can hold elements of any size you wish.

Answer (score 0):

C as a language does not have generics. C++ does through templates.

You can use some C preprocessor hacks to achieve generic-like behaviour, but it's not easy to do.

This is how I have used preprocessor macros to implement a list/stack with generics in C:

```
#define list_t(type) struct { \
    type *list; \
    ssize_t size; \
    size_t maxlength; \
}

#define list_init(listarg) list_init_size( (listarg), 1024)
#define list_init_flags(listarg, flags) list_init_size_flags( (listarg), 1024, (flags))
#define list_init_size( _list, initsize) list_init_size_flags((_list), (initsize), 0)
#define list_init_size_flags( _list, initsize, flags) list_init_size_alloc((_list), (initsize), sizeof((_list)->list[0]), (flags))

static inline void list_init_size_alloc( void * const _list, size_t initsize, size_t objectsize, int flags) {
    list_t(void) * list = _list;
    list->size = 0;

    if (flags & 1) { // use thread safe shared memory expansion
        // removed for readability
        // this part had shared memory capability
    } else {
        if(!(list->list = malloc(initsize * objectsize))) {
            perror("malloc");
            abort();
        }
    }

    list->maxlength = initsize;
}

#define list_free(listarg) free((listarg).list)


#define list_qsort(listarg, comparator) qsort((listarg).list, (listarg).size, sizeof((listarg).list[0]), comparator)

#define list_new_empty( _list) (list_check_length(_list) ? -1 : (memset((_list)->list + (_list)->size, 0, sizeof((_list)->list[0])) , (_list)->size++))
#define list_insert_fast( _list, object) (list_check_length(_list) ? -1 : (((_list)->list[(_list)->size] = (object)), (_list)->size++))

#define list_push list_insert_fast
#define list_pop( _list) (_list)->list[--((_list)->size)]

#define list_check_length(_list) list_check_length_real(_list, sizeof((_list)->list[0]))
static inline int list_check_length_real(void * const _list, size_t objectsize) {
    list_t(void) * list = _list;
    if (list->size >= list->maxlength) { // enlarge the array
        void *tmp = realloc(list->list, list->maxlength * 2 * objectsize);
        if (tmp) {
            list->list = tmp; 
            list->maxlength *=2;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I stripped down the code to the bare minimum. Hope this gives you some ideas.

Use:

```
list_t(int) mylist;
list_init(&mylist);
list_insert_fast(&mylist, 15);

printf("%d\n", mylist.list[0]);
```

Comment: @qrdl Yeah, but as far as I can tell those generics are switch statements for a finite amount of preprogrammed types. Not applicable to the case at hand.